# MongoDB Find an element in an array (subdocument)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update an array field in an subdocument array in my collection. My collection looks like this:

```
{
 _id:"1",
 employees:[{ eid:"2",
              ename:"test",
              is_user:true
             },
             { eid:"3",
              ename:"test2",
              is_user:true
             }
           ]
}
```

I am trying to update the is_user status and am trying it the following way:

```
db.users.update({_id:"1","employees.eid":"2"},{$set:"employees.$.is_user":true},true);
```

I also tried :

```
db.users.update({_id:"1","employees.$.eid":"2"},{$set:"employees.$.is_user":true},true);
```

But when I run a find, for the query:

```
db.users.find({_id:"1","employees.eid":"2"});
```

it still gives me nothing. Can anybody help me on this ?
Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That does work.

```
> db.test.insert({_id:"1", employees:[{ eid:"2", ename:"test", is_user:true }, { eid:"3", ename:"test2", is_user:true } ] })
> db.test.find({_id:"1","employees.eid":"2"});
{ "_id" : "1", "employees" : [  {   "eid" : "2",    "ename" : "test",  "is_user" : true },  {   "eid" : "3",    "ename" : "test2", "is_user" : true } ] }
```

For the `$` operator you want to use it like:

```
> db.test.insert({_id:"1", employees:[{ eid:"2", ename:"test", is_user:false }, { eid:"3", ename:"test2", is_user:false } ] })
> db.test.find({_id:"1", "employees.eid":"2", "employees.is_user": true});
> db.test.update({_id:"1", "employees.eid":"2"}, {$set: {"employees.$.is_user": true}});
> db.test.find({_id:"1", "employees.eid":"2", "employees.is_user": true});
{ "_id" : "1", "employees" : [  {   "eid" : "2",    "ename" : "test",   "is_user" : true },     {   "eid" : "3",    "ename" : "test2",  "is_user" : false } ] }
```

Notice how the insert of `is_user` is set to `false` on both objects in the array and after the update the matching object is updated from `false` to `true`, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes.. it does, but I wanna just get the array element I wanna update. When I run an update, the is_user field is not updated.

Comment: Is there a typo on one of the queries u typed, because I dont see an update query.

Comment: Even this doesnt work for me :(

db.users.update({_id:"1","employees.eid":"2"},{$set:{"employees.$.is_user":true}},true);

Comment: Sorry, missed the update query, you are right, just copied it.

Comment: Pretty much what my update was doing.. But got it working now.. Thanks a lot dude.. I was trying with the positional operator on the 'query' part, but guess thats not rt.. Thanks a ton again :)

People like you, get us going :) Thanks for those super quick replies